# How to install AWS CLI in docker container based on image "python:2.7"

Tags: docker, aws-cli

I have a dockerfile that looks like this:

```
FROM python:2.7
RUN pip install awscli --upgrade --user
```

Once the docker image is built from this dockerfile, I run it. But when I get into the container and try to run the AWS CLI, it can't find it, because it is not in the PATH environment variable:

```
$ docker exec -ti ec4934370e37 /bin/bash

root@ec4934370e37:~# aws
bash: aws: command not found

root@ec4934370e37:/# find / -name aws
/root/.local/bin/aws

root@ec4934370e37:/# /root/.local/bin/aws --version
aws-cli/1.15.81 Python/2.7.15 Linux/4.9.87-linuxkit-aufs botocore/1.10.80

root@ec4934370e37:/# env | grep PATH
PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
```

What is the best/easiest/least-hacky way to make sure that the AWSCLI is usable by being included in the PATH variable? Can this be done from inside the dockerfile itself?

Comment: `ENV PATH=/root/.local/bin:$PATH` will probably work -- though if you remove `--user` it'll likely install into `/usr/local/bin` and be on the `PATH` already!

Comment: Yep. Removing the `--user` worked!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have two options here.

The first is to explicitly put the `root` user's local bin on the `PATH` with something like

```
ENV PATH=/root/.local/bin:$PATH
```

The second is to drop the `--user` argument on your `pip install`.  By default, `pip` should write to `/usr/local/bin` which will be on your `PATH` already

Comment: i'm a noob, but will adding that path to the docker image not tell the container to use other dependencies from your local path? like, will it point to your host machine's path and use the host's python?

Comment: @greenie-beans no that's not at all how containers work

Answer (score 5):

In case you just need `aws` on your CI server:

```
FROM python:alpine

ARG CLI_VERSION=1.16.310

RUN pip install --no-cache-dir awscli==$CLI_VERSION && \
    mkdir /root/.aws

VOLUME /root/.aws/

ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/local/bin/aws"]
```

Build and tag as `aws`:

```
docker build -t aws .
```

Which can be used in this way:

```
docker run --rm -v /root/aws-cli/.aws:/root/.aws -ti aws ecr get-login --no-include-email --region us-west-2
```

Or:

```
docker run --rm -e  AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=AKIABCDEFGHIJKLMONP -e "AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=abcdefghijklmnopqrstvwxyz" -ti aws ecr get-login --no-include-email --region us-west-2
```